# Error processingorg.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.reactiveElasticsearchClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, rest-client

I have updated springboot(2.7.11) version + springcloud version(2021.0.3) + java version (17)
and also converted my bootstrap.properties to yml file and after that i am getting this error below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.reactiveElasticsearchClient
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at cydea.tech.cdpdatastorage.CdpDataStorageApplication.main(CdpDataStorageApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ReactiveElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/ClientConfiguration$ClientConfigurationCallback
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration$ClientConfigurationCallback
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I have reviewed all the URLs and my YAML format, but I haven't made any progress. Although I have added the WebFlux dependency, the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Did you check elastic server version and rest clients version conflict with Spring boot after update?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Changes in build.gradle:

```
- implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
+ implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).